# Using ajax.dataSrc Option results `No matching records found`

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, webforms, datatables

I have PHP project which uses [datatables](https://datatables.net). It works fine and great.

Continue to the next project which uses ASP.NET Webforms, I have a problem especially at the ajax part. Different like in PHP, in ASP.NET, I got the response with a single parameter in the JSON object called `d`. Therefore I have to alter the response by using [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).

However, It turns out that when I implement it in ASP project, it shows `No matching records found`. Here is the `ajax.dataSrc` code:

```
dataTable: {
    ajax: {
    type: 'POST',
    url: window.location.href + '/GetData',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    dataSrc: function (json) {
         return $.parseJSON(json.d);
    }
}
```

In order to test the `ajax.dataSrc`, I tried to implement it in the PHP project (the one that works fine), tried to simply use `ajax.dataSrc` in it and pass the raw response without any changing. Here is my testing code in PHP project:

```
dataSrc: function (json) {
    return json;
}
```

It turns out the table shows `No matching records found` as well. I conclude that there must be something wrong with my `ajax.dataSrc`.

So, for the question, do I use the `ajax.dataSrc` in correct way? If not, could you please show me an example, at least simply use `ajax.dataSrc` and pass raw response?

Comment: `return json.d` ..?

Comment: @davidkonrad still no luck in there unfortunately.